# UnimplementedError (FLUTTER)

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, widget, throw, stateful

I'm super new at coding with Flutter and following this course that let's me create stateful widget. The problem is when I do, I get this throw UnimplementedError();
It should return to null. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

```
my code:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      "What's your favourite color?",
      "What's your favourite animal?",
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "My First App",
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              questions[questionIndex],
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Answer 1"),
              onPressed: answerQuestion,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Answer 2"),
              onPressed: answerQuestion,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Answer 3"),
              onPressed: answerQuestion,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're getting UnimplementedError error because you're throwing the exception inside createState.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `createState()` method includes a `TODO` comment:

```
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  // TODO: implement createState
  throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

This comment is a kind reminder that we have something left to do.

However, the `throw UnimplementedError()` makes the reminder less friendly, forcing us to complete our `TODO` task and remove the `UnimplementedError()` line to make it work:

```
MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
```

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to select the answer as correct